# How to take input in JavaScript in Visual Studio but it shows error-->ReferenceError: prompt is not defined

Tags: javascript

How to take input in JavaScript in Visual Studio but it shows error-->ReferenceError: prompt is not defined

I tried a lot but when I searched on google it shows that use prompt but it is only able to run for browser and on html but what if I want to practice on my VS.

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead.